# Segmentation fault, not sure of orgins

Tags: c++, string, function, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that reads input and then reverses a string.
So I might enter "racecars" it should reverse it to "sracecar". I am not sure why I am getting a segmentation fault. My debugger was not clear on where my segfault is it either. I am using a gdb debugger in vim.

How would I be able to make my program reverse input in the turnaround function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

 string turnaround(string &input);

int main(){

  cout << "enter some string to reverso" << endl;
  string input;
  getline(cin,input);

  turnaround(input);
  //cout << "your input is " << input << endl;

  return 0;
}

string turnaround (string & input){

  input = string(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of exiting a non-void function without encountering a `return` statement.

Comment: turnaround Doesn't return anything ! How did you compile your code ?

Comment: Since `turnaround()` is modifying `input`, either make it return `void` or add a `return input` statement at the end.    Either way, that will avoid undefined behaviour associated with "falling off the end" of the function.   Also, turn up compiler warnings - most compilers, if appropriately configured, will warn about falling off the end of a non-`void` function.

Comment: FWIW, the program runs fine when compiled with g++ (version 5.3,0) , but segfaults when compiled with clang++ (Apple LLVM version 5.1).

Answer (score 1):

The new reversed string you are creating in turnarround is no longer available once you leave scope of turnaround. So you have made input refering to no longer existing object and that's why the segfault.

Try the following way:

```
 string turnaround(const string& input)
 {
    return string(input.rbegin(),input.rend());
 }
```

Comment: That is not correct, as the new string is copy-assigned to `input`. Hence, it will not be a dangling reference. The answer is that it is undefined behaviour to omit the return statement.

Comment: ... and to clarify: references cannot be reseated, so the assignment will not make `input` refer to another object, it assigns a new value to the object that `input` refers to.